# Is there a way to tell if a solana transaction took place on Raydium?

Tags: transactions, account

Is there a way to tell if a solana transaction took place on Raydium? I am looking at transactions based on a user's address and I noticed that sometimes Raydium appears in the accounts array. Basically my goal is to let a user know if they have transactions that took place on Raydium, Serum, Orca, or some other decentralized exchange.

Here is the corresponding tx hash: https://solana.fm/tx/4xV2HoMnXee3BZ35Uh32bna3HGLxZSS3ox6Yn17g9jucDGYCxAMvYocoNdXrw8njEjVT3kVGKxfM4ZXaiuaYSzmH

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to inspect the program ID of each instruction in each transaction looking for those that match each DEX program. For each matching instruction that you find, you then need to decode the data (which is program-specific) to determine if it is one that does something your users would consider interesting.